# VSCode not using wsl2 git after moving installs

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

I am running Ubuntu-20.0.4 and docker desktop in WSL2 on Windows 10 Pro. I recently moved the distributions onto another drive using export/import, keeping the same names by first unregistering the distributions. Everything works as expected, with the exception of git.

Git works fine using the integrated shell, but is prompting me to add global config when trying to commit via the ide. This leads me to believe that it is not using the remote git. How can I verify this, and are there any fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This leads me to believe that it is not using the remote git

Then you could open the VSCode settings, and put under `Git Path` the full path of the git you are expecting it to use.

That way, independently of the `$PATH` inherited by VSCode when running, said IDE would use the exact Git you need.

---

You also have to check with which account VSCode is running, or it would access the *wrong* "global" settings (IE the ones from *another* account).

The [OP Romski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/384646/romski) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70658957/vscode-not-using-wsl2-git-after-moving-installs/70674480#comment124967822_70674480):

> I noticed that files created in VSCode were owned by `root`.
> The fix was to set the default user `<distribution>` `config --default-user <username>`. I

Comment: My settings were set to `"git.path": "/usr/local/bin/git"`. in WSL, my git is actually installed at `/usr/bin/git`. Regardless of the value I use, it's still not using the global git config from WSL. As an aside, when I view the settings.json, I get the following warning for that setting: `This setting cannot be applied in this window. It will be applied when you open a local window.`

Comment: @Romski Maybe the user account used by VScode in WSL is not the one which includes the global config you want. What does id -a returns when executed in a integrated terminal in VSCode?

Comment: You are correct. I noticed that files created in vscode were owned by root. The fix was to set the default user `<distribution> config --default-user <username>`. If you'd like to update your answer, I'll mark it as accepted- thanks

Comment: @Romski Good catch, well done. I have updated the answer accordingly.